# Mysql query ordered by two integer columns

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Sorry my basic question, I am two hours searching in stackoverflow. I have a mysql table where I need to select ordering by two integer columns.

```
partners
+----+--------+----------+
| id | status |   name   |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 |    0   |   Adam   |
|  2 |    1   |  Charles |
|  3 |    1   |   Bob    |
|  4 |    0   |  Raven   |
+----+--------+----------+
```

When I use: `mysql_query("SELECT name FROM partners ORDER BY id DESC, status DESC");`

The result is:

```
Raven
Bob
Charles
Adam
```

But I need this result, always the status=1 on the top:

```
Bob
Charles
Raven
Adam
```

Where I'm doing wrong in the query?

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql_query("SELECT name FROM partners ORDER BY status DESC, id DESC");
```

Put the things you want to sort by in the order you want them sorted.

Answer (score 1):

`status = 1` always shown top and others sorted by DESC.

```
SELECT name, IF(status = 1, 99999999, status) as sts
FROM partner
ORDER BY sts DESC;
```

i.e. use `IF()` to convert 1 to some higher value.